# Delete Dual Boot on Windows

Tags: kali-linux, dual-boot, grub

I have Windows 10 operating system on HP Notebook laptop. I have installed Kali Linux on another partition and both the operating systems work fine (I am able to use both of them).Whenever I turn on the laptop, I am directly taken to Windows 10 and not given an option for Kali Linux.
To boot into Kali Linux I have to each time press F9 to show boot options then i have to choose kali.

My problem is: i want to delete dual boot (kali Linux) but i am confused that does the GRUB is installed or not. To delete kali, deleting kali partition is enough or is something more i have to do..
plz help i don't know much... learner...
any help is appriciated... thanks in advancee...

Comment: To make sure I understand you, you want to make it so you have no Kali Linux at all, and it's Windows only, correct? Or are you trying to do something else?

Comment: i just want to delete kali from dual boot and use it on virtualbox...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Windows(which seems to be the default) bootloader does not know about your Linux. It will be best if you configure your Linux GRUB to know about your Windows partition and use it as a default bootloader.

Here you can see an example guide:

https://itsfoss.com/grub-customizer-ubuntu/

It has an ubuntu as an example, but GRUB configuration should not be any different.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to delete Kali, you should go into windows and open Disk/Partition Manager, delete the partition that Kali was installed on then create a Linux live file system on a USB and boot to it, this should be pretty easy as you would've done it to install Kali. go into terminal and type `sudo mkdir /mnt/1 ; sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/1 ; cd /mnt/1/EFI/; rm -r Kali` then you can reboot back into windows and Kali is gone and i would recommend extending your windows partition back to fill the entire drive by opening Disk/Partition Manager and right clicking the main partition(usually the biggest one) and pressing extend and select the highest size